# put an interval between .each() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('.action-button').each(function(i, obj) { $(obj).trigger('click') });
```

I wanted to put a delay between each iteration of the loop, ideally a 5 second delay. How do I do so? Is it possible to use setTimeout?

Comment: This sounds like a poor solution to a different problem. What is the issue you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should work with `setTimeout`

Try this

```
$('.action-button').each(function(i, obj) { 
   setTimeout(function () {
      $(obj).trigger('click')
   },500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work.

```
$('.action-button').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(obj).delay(5000 * i).click();
});
```

jQuery's `.each()`, when given an argument such as the `i` here, will increment every loop.

Therefore you could use this to multiply the original time * i, this would cause the first click to be called after 5 seconds, the next after 10 seconds.

If you want the first element to be also delayed, you should add 1 to `i` as the first index is always 0.

```
$('.action-button').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(obj).delay(5000 * (i + 1)).click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.action-button').each(function(i, obj) 
    { 

    $(obj).delay(i*500).trigger('click') 


    });
```

Comment: This would click every object after a single 500ms delay.

Comment: I would modify this by using the index (i) as a multiplier on the 500 ... so $(obj).delay(i*500).trigger('click')

Comment: so something like this? $(obj).delay(i * 2000).trigger('click');